# Вывести поле на экран

Tags: wordpress

Как вывести это поле на экран? Какая там апи функция?

[image]

Comment: С чего вы взяли что эта функция вообще существует? Наверняка имя этого файла есть в бд, почему бы просто не взять его оттуда так же, как оно выводится в примере?

Comment: Простите конечно, но разве эта ссылка не на экране выведена? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image_src - если я вас павильно понял... :)))

Или http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_attachment_link